# Create my own Attribute with Action as parameter type

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I want to create my own `Attribute` in `C# .Net` with an argument of `Action` type, like this:

```
 public class TestAttribute : Attribute
 {
        public Action MethodToExecute;
 }
```

And the use:

```
 [TestAttribute(MethodToExecute = () => Test())]
 public string VersaoLinha { get; set; }

 public static string Test()
 {
     return string.Empty;
 }
```

But so, I've the error `Is not a valid argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type`. Has a way to do this?

Comment: Similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705386/is-it-possible-to-have-a-delegate-as-attribute-parameter

Comment: And to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357569/passing-func-as-an-attribute-parameter-to-secure-mvc-routes